# What is reddit's user agent?

Tags: nginx, user-agent

Does anyone know what the user agent is for reddit? I have hotlink protection enabled on my site but I want to allow a reddit to hotlink my image however I don't know know what their user agent is.

Comment: There isn't just a single user agent when something is hot linked.

Comment: You really need to be looking at the referrer, rather than user agent.